# Expressing the Normal Distribution as a Member of the Exponential Family

Tags: normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

**Background Info:**
I am looking for a more general form for the exponential family of distributions. Let's start by considering the normal distribution:

$$p(y|\mu,\sigma^2)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}\exp(\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y-\mu)^2\})$$.

**Question:**

Demonstrate that the normal distribution (without considering the variance equal to 1) is an exponential distribution. Specifically, identify the terms $b(y)$, $\eta$, $T(y)$, and $a(\eta)$ in the exponential distribution probability function, which is given by:

$$p(y;\eta)=b(y)\exp\{\eta^\top T(y) - a(\eta)\}$$.

Since $\sigma^2$ is a variable here, $\eta$ and $T(y)$ will be two-dimensional vectors. Assume $\eta = [\eta_1  \  \eta_2]^\top$ for consistent notation. Also, express $a(\eta)$ in terms of $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$.

Comment: 1) Nowadays a distribution is a probability, not a family of probabilities. Avoid the old expression 'this distribution belongs to THE exponential family' but say this family of distributions is an exponential family.   2) For this reason, do not say that the nornal law $N(m,1)$ is an exponential distribution, which is something else, namely  a distribution on $(0,\infty)$ such that $\Pr(X>x)=e^{-\lambda x}.$